# How do I create an interface defining a function, that allows for any number of variables in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using an object, that holds unlimited number of functions. To define the type of this object I've create a new interface as follows:

```
export interface Functions {
  [key: string]: () => void;
}
```

Then I had some functions that would take a variable and I got an error, because this signature interface is for a function that takes no variables, so I've changed it to this:

```
export interface Functions {
  [key: string]: (variables?: any) => void;
}
```

Which worked, but now I have a function that would take 2 variables. I can just do this:

```
export interface Functions {
  [key: string]: (variableOne?: any, variableTwo?: any) => void;
}
```

But that doesn't feel like the correct way to go about solving this. How can I just define it as a function that may take an unlimited amount of variables, or none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax?

```
export interface Functions {
  [key: string]: (...variables: any[]) => void;
}
```

Comment: Yes this did what I needed! Thank you.

Comment: The `...parameter` syntax is known as the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: I've been using it in array and objects, but first time using it in a function.